# Conexão SQL com PHP

Tags: php, sql

Tenho o seguinte PHP, estou utilizando o WAMP, e como na imagem abaixo, as dll's estão ativas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?php
$server = "dblinx";
$connection = array("Database"=>"Linx", "UID"=>"root","PWD"=>"root");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connection);

if ($conn) {
  echo "Connected!";
} else {
  echo "Connection failed<br>";
  die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
}
?>
```

Porém, sempre aparece isso quando tento abrir a página:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Ja adicionei os extensions no PHP.ini

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Está tentando conectar ao SQL Server?

Comment: Provavelmente está faltando você incluir as extensões em seu php.ini que fica no mesmo caminho das dlls. Vou inserir na resposta para verificar se resolve.

Comment: Os drivers `pdo` só seriam necessários se estivesse usando PDO. Um possível problema, é estar usando 32bits e não 64bits (o xampp ou sql server?, até eu fiquei na dúvida agora), assim dá-se o erro.

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com o site da Microsoft é necessário a inclusão no php.ini conforme abaixo.

extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll

Referência:

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Ja adiconei nos extensions, mesmo assim ele continua aparecendo esse erro

Comment: Após adicionar a extensão é necessário reiniciar o seu servidor de aplicação. Pode compartilhar o que acrescentou em seu php.ini editando sua pergunta

Comment: Adicionei na pergunta, e sim, ja reiniciei o servidor, algumas vezes já hahah

Comment: Verifica se seu wamp está com o php7 selecionado. E verifica o que o RBZ comentou também.